# CLIPProcessor hangs on getting image feature under corner case on specific image

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tokenize, embedding, vector-database

I am working on building a local image similarity search program using the CLIP model from Hugging Face's transformers library, specifically the `openai--clip-vit-base-patch16` model. I have encountered a peculiar issue that I can reliably reproduce, and I'm seeking insights into its root cause.

Technical Details:

- Platform: OSX, Apple silicon M1Max
- Model: `openai--clip-vit-base-patch16`
- Processor Object: `self.processor: CLIPProcessor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(model)`
- Embedding Method: `self.processor(images=img, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)  # where img is a PIL.Image object.`
- Python version: 3.10.13
- Python package version: `transformers==4.36.2`, `torch==2.1.2`, `numpy==1.26.2`

Program flow:

1. Scan phase: Scan and embeds all images from a given library folder using the embedding method above and build vector index for result
2. Search phase: Embeds a new image by reusing the same CLIPProcessor object and searches within the previously scanned results to get similar images
3. Possible re-scan: Update the library's all embeddings by an identical re-scan operation, this operation also simply reuse the same CLIPProcessor object

(And importantly, all above operations call the same processor object, and only the mbedding method is called.)

The strange corner case issue:

1. I can successfully perform an initial scan, embedding ALL images in a given library using
2. I can successfully perform multiple similar search requests
3. The problem arises when I attempt to perform a re-scan after at least one search operation. During the re-scan, the program hangs on a specific image in the library (this specific image can successfully embedded in the initial scan). The CPU load drops from 100% to 1%, and the program gets stuck in the embedding method.

Debugging:
Upon debugging, I found that the hang occurs in the `transformers->feature_extraction_utils.py->BatchFeature.convert_to_tensors()` function. Specifically, within the `elif tensor_type == TensorType.PYTORCH:` branch, the hang is observed at `return torch.tensor(value)`.

The hang seems to be related to Torch, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact issue. The interruption behaves like a hang, and neither Ctrl+C (SIGINT) nor any other signals can stop the program. Only SIGKILL works.

The sample special image that can be successfully embedded in the first scan, but hangs in second scan after a search operation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ao39KOX0SrmZOMou69NNDbHSdhEr0yAv/view?usp=sharing. After removing this image from library, a rescan can successfully continue.

I am looking for insights into why the re-scan hangs on a specific image after at least one search operation. Any suggestions for debugging further or potential solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated.